# How do I resolve this? I am trying to run my django app and am getting this error

Tags: python, django

myapp.AuthPermission.content_type: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'DjangoContentType', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

myapp.AuthPermission.content_type: (fields.E307) The field myapp.AuthPermission.content_type was declared with a lazy reference to 'myapp.djangocontenttype',
but app 'myapp' doesn't provide model 'djangocontenttype'.

my model.py

from django.db import models

```
class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


class BackgroundTask(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    task_params = models.TextField()
    task_hash = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    run_at = models.DateTimeField()
    repeat = models.BigIntegerField()
    repeat_until = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    queue = models.CharField(max_length=190, blank=True, null=True)
    attempts = models.IntegerField()
    failed_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_error = models.TextField()
    locked_by = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    locked_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    creator_object_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    creator_content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'background_task'


class BackgroundTaskCompletedtask(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    task_params = models.TextField()
    task_hash = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    run_at = models.DateTimeField()
    repeat = models.BigIntegerField()
    repeat_until = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    queue = models.CharField(max_length=190, blank=True, null=True)
    attempts = models.IntegerField()
    failed_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_error = models.TextField()
    locked_by = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    locked_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    creator_object_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    creator_content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'background_task_completedtask'


class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.SmallIntegerField()
    change_message = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('MyappUser', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'


class DjangoCeleryBeatClockedschedule(models.Model):
    clocked_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_celery_beat_clockedschedule'


class DjangoCeleryBeatCrontabschedule(models.Model):
    minute = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    hour = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    day_of_week = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    day_of_month = models.CharField(max_length=124)
    month_of_year = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=63)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_celery_beat_crontabschedule'


class DjangoCeleryBeatIntervalschedule(models.Model):
    every = models.IntegerField()
    period = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_celery_beat_intervalschedule'


class DjangoCeleryBeatPeriodictask(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    args = models.TextField()
    kwargs = models.TextField()
    queue = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    exchange = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    routing_key = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    expires = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField()
    last_run_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_run_count = models.IntegerField()
    date_changed = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField()
    crontab = models.ForeignKey(DjangoCeleryBeatCrontabschedule, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    interval = models.ForeignKey(DjangoCeleryBeatIntervalschedule, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    solar = models.ForeignKey('DjangoCeleryBeatSolarschedule', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    one_off = models.BooleanField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    headers = models.TextField()
    clocked = models.ForeignKey(DjangoCeleryBeatClockedschedule, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    expire_seconds = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_celery_beat_periodictask'


class DjangoCeleryBeatPeriodictasks(models.Model):
    ident = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_celery_beat_periodictasks'


class DjangoCeleryBeatSolarschedule(models.Model):
    event = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_celery_beat_solarschedule'
        unique_together = (('event', 'latitude', 'longitude'),)


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'


class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'



class MyappUserGroups(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyappUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Myapp_user_groups'
        unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


class MyappUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyappUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Myapp_user_user_permissions'
        unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)
```

Comment: Share `models.py`.

Comment: @NixonSparrow I dont need djangocontenttype in my models.py

Comment: Do you have `'django.contrib.contenttypes'` in `INSTALLED_APSS` list of your `settings.py`?

Comment: @alamshafi2263 yes i have it

Comment: It'd be better to have a look at the concerned model.

Comment: @alamshafi2263 I have included it then

Comment: It seems like you have a models file generated by `inspectdb` management command. If the database was being used by a django app before then it should have the `DjangoContentType` model in there.

Comment: You didn't include imports. Do you import `DjangoContentType`? It specifically points to that line: `content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)`

Answer (score 1):

The `models.py` looks like it has been generated from a legacy database via `inspectdb` command. Either regenerate the models file or Add the following to your `models.py` file -

```py
class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)
```

Comment: alamshafi2263 thanks,,I arleady figure out where I was wrong